# Start new Activity with button with FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP on Android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

Basically Im trying start new Activity with button. Problem is in MainActivity class Im using:

```
mPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this,
            getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
```

I think thats reason why when Im trying start new activity I still can see only MainActivity because its still on the TOP of screen. 
 I tried use this:

```
public void handleClick(View v){
//Create an intent to start the new activity.
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setClass(this,Page2Activity.class);
startActivity(intent); 
}
```

but still can't see new activity opened.
Is it way how I can start new Activity on the top of screen? 
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you exactly trying to do?

To start a new Activity B from Activity A you have to do:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, B.class);
startActivity(i);
```

you could try to set

```
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
```

Comment: I just add i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) and it looks it works :) Thanks

Comment: No problem :) for more information on Tasks take a look at http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html